# Azure function Graph API Insufficient privileges

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've created a C# function in Azure and it looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{

    log.Info("---- Gestartet ----");
    var token = await HttpAppAuthenticationAsync();
    log.Info("---- Token: " + token.ToString());

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var user = "username@XXXXX.com";
    var userExists = await DoesUserExistsAsync(client, user, log);

    if(userExists)
    {
        log.Info("Der Benutzer existiert.");
    }
    else {
        log.Info("Benutzer nicht gefunden.");
    }
}

public static async Task<string> HttpAppAuthenticationAsync()
{
    //log.Info("---- Start ----");

    //  Constants
    var tenant = "2XXXXXCC6-c789-41XX-9XXX-XXXXXXXXXX";
    var resource = "https://graph.windows.net/";
    var clientID = "5XXXXef-4905-4XXf-8XXa-bXXXXXXX2";
    var secret = "5GFzeg6VyrkJYUJ8XXXXXXXeKbjYaXXX7PlNpFkkg=";

    var webClient = new WebClient();

    var requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();

    requestParameters.Add("resource", resource);
    requestParameters.Add("client_id", clientID);
    requestParameters.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    requestParameters.Add("client_secret", secret);

    var url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token";
    var responsebytes = await webClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, "POST", requestParameters);
    var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responsebody);
    var token = obj["access_token"].Value<string>();
    //log.Info("HIER: " + token);
    return token;
}

private static async Task<bool> DoesUserExistsAsync(HttpClient client, string user, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("---- Suche Benutzer ----");
    try
    {
        var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.net/v1.0/users/user");

        return true;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {

        return false;
    }
}
```

In my log I get the bearer token. But then result of `DoesUserExistsAsync` is false.
If I send an request via Postman with the token I get following response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "10XXX850-XXX-4d72-b6cf-78X308XXXXX0",
            "date": "2017-09-07T14:03:58"
        }
    }
}
```

In the Azure AD I created an App and the permissions are:
[image: Function with allowd Azure AD login]

[image: Permisions for function-app]

(I gave all permisions only to test what`s wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `client_credentials`, there is no "user". That OAUTH grant only authenticates your application, not an actual user.

When using `client_credentials`, only the scopes listed under "Application Permissions" are applicable. Since you don't have a user authenticated, there isn't a user to "delegate" to your app.

Application Permissions are also unique in that every one of them requires [Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) before your app can use them. Without consent, your application will have insufficient privileges to complete *any* operation.

Also, this call won't return anything:

```cs
await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.net/v1.0/users/user");
```

I assume what you're really looking for is:

```cs
private async Task<bool> DoesUserExistsAsync(HttpClient client, string userPrincipalName, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("---- Suche Benutzer ----");
    try
    {
        var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.net/v1.0/users/" 
                                                  + userPrincipalName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The consent really just assigns those "roles" to the service principal :) It is required since creating those AppRoleAssignments requires pretty much admin access to the directory. And specifying that an app *requires* a role/permission is a separate thing from actually *granting* the permission.

Comment: Excellent point and fair correction. I often find going into service pricipal and and roles ends up confusing people who don't have an AD background. Particularly if in the end, they just want to get Graph to return some data. :-)

Comment: Agreed, your answer is fine as it is, just wanted to expand in case someone is curious.